# How to enforce lazy loading of entities on certain conditions

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, seam

We have an JPA @Entity class (say User) which has a @ManyToOne reference (say Address) loaded using the EAGER option which in turn loads it's own @ManyToOne fields (say Country) in a EAGER fashion.

We use the [EntityQuery](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/api/org/jboss/seam/framework/EntityQuery.html) interface to count the list of User's based on a search criteria, during such a load all the @ManyToOne fields which have been marked as EAGER get loaded. But in order to perform a EntityQuery.resultCount(), I actually don't need to load the @ManyToOne fields. Is there a way to prevent loading of the EAGER fields in such cases so that we can avoid the unnecessary joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [aggregate functions](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbwa)(COUNT in your case) if all you need is the number of records ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the number of rows *only*, use the `COUNT` aggregate function, rather than `getResultCount()`.

Otherwise, you can switch the default behaviour to lazy, and load the items by calling `Hibernate.initialize(entity)`. But that's tedious.

Comment: trying to initialize entities is quite error prone, i wouldn't want to venture down that path. I would also prefer the code to be implementation agnostic as possible.

Comment: well, COUNT is rather standard.